# TypeScript Class Being Used In Cast Not Loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I've created a model in TypeScript that I'm using in a cast.  When running the application, the model is not loaded and I'm unable to use any functions on that model.

**Model**

```
export class DataIDElement extends HTMLElement {
    get dataID(): number {
        var attributes: NamedNodeMap = this.attributes;
        var dataIDAttribute: Attr = attributes.getNamedItem("data-id");

        if (!dataIDAttribute) { 
            //throw error
        }

        var value: number = Number(dataIDAttribute.value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Angular Component (Where model is being imported)**

```
import { DataIDElement } from '../../models/dataIdElement';

export class PersonComponent
{
    personClicked(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        var element: DataIDElement = <DataIDElement>event.target;

        // This code always returns undefined (model isn't loaded)
        var personID: number = element.dataID;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is not a cast it's a type assertion. You are just saying that whatever is inside event.target is of the type DataIDElement. It doesn't create a new instance of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing there is a type assertion. That only overwrites the type inference of the compiler to make it believe that **event.target** is of the type **DataIDElement**. It doesn't create a new instance of **DataIDElement**.

If you want to create an instance of **DataIDElement** you need to create it using **new**.

**DataIDElement** would look something like this:

```
export class DataIDElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(private target: HTMLElement) {}
    get dataID(): number {
        var attributes: NamedNodeMap = this.target.attributes;
        var dataIDAttribute: Attr = attributes.getNamedItem("data-id");

        if (!dataIDAttribute) { 
            //throw error
        }

        var value: number = Number(dataIDAttribute.value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

And would be used like this:

```js
import { DataIDElement } from '../../models/dataIdElement';

export class PersonComponent
{
    personClicked(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        var element: DataIDElement = new DataIDElement(event.target);

        // This code always returns undefined (model isn't loaded)
        var personID: number = element.dataID;
    }
}
```